# Error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger"

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, jboss, nosuchmethoderror

I am trying to build 1 hybrid test project using spring + hibernate. After deploying... I am getting frustrated with this error.. and searched in google but still not getting it working...

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.hibernate.annotations.common.util.impl.LoggerFactory.make(LoggerFactory.java:34)
at org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:34)
at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit>(JavaReflectionManager.java:73)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.reset(AnnotationConfiguration.java:311)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:216)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:220)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.<init>(AnnotationConfiguration.java:168)
```

Trying jboss-logger 3.1.0.CR2, as well as a variety of different jboss-logging, different versions.

How to resolve it?

Below is image attached to have a look if any version concurrencies are present or any dependencies are missing...
[image: Library structure for project]

Comment: https://community.jboss.org/message/604269

Comment: Thanks @KazekageGaara, but they are using maven shade and i dont wanna go and do setup for maven and even i am not gonna use maven, i went through this solution as well but... not useful.. if you can let me know any more idea that would be great... :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 10):

I solved it by removing `jboss-common-client-3.2.3.jar`.

Comment: had same problem with "jboss-common-core" "2.2.17.GA"
added exclusion for "org.jboss.logging" "jboss-logging-spi"

Answer (score 6):

Got the same problem with org.jboss.logging-3.1.0.GA needed by Springframework 4.1.3 Final.

The solution for me was to exclude org.jboss.logging coming from Hibernate and add org.jboss.logging-3.2.0.Final to my project in the pom.xml.
As specify [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBLOGGING-70) org.jboss.logging-3.1.0.GA (and CR2) has a failure in LoggerProviders detection and it is fixed in 3.2.0 Final [Voir le Github de Jboss Logging](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logging/commit/787577b1d42f49ba464fc11c2ac5fd307dfdccb0)

Answer (score 3):

Is it an incorrect version of JBoss Logging jar on your client classpath? If you have JBoss 7.1.0 Final version then remove all the JAR filesfrom your classpath and add only one client JAR file (jboss-client-7.1.0.Final.jar) which is located in AS7_HOME/bin/client.

For further reference, you can see [this](http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/ejb3/how-to-create-a-simple-ejb3-project-in-eclipse-jboss-7-1/).

Comment: I am using tomcat not jboss. do you think this will still help?

Comment: It should. If you don't want to risk it, then create a new project to be on the safer end.

Comment: Check your classpath. It has to be a different version of JBoss Logging getting loaded.

Comment: I already resolved that... some how by putting 1 by 1 jar files and check which are creating problem. anyways putting this as accepted. as no other tried. :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I removed glassfish libraries from buildpath, and problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with **jboss-4.2.3GA**.

This happened because in the **[JBOSS_HOME]\lib** folder there is a **jboss-common.jar** library that also has an `org.jboss.logging.Logger` class and this is the one that takes into account.

My solution was to add the **jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar** library to the **[JBOSS_HOME]\lib\endorsed** folder and take into account that when starting the server it has the option `-Djava.endorsed.dirs = [JBOSS_HOME]\lib\endorsed`.

After this, it started showing a ***warning*** from ***java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getLoggerPlugin()Lorg/jboss/logging/LoggerPlugin;***

...but that is another matter.