# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm just trying to learn Hibernate (version 4 final) but I have a problem when trying to create the session factory. Here is some code related to the problem:

full error log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:192)
at DAO.bdDAO.createSessionFactory(bdDAO.java:16)
at DAO.CategorieTechnicienDAO.Add(CategorieTechnicienDAO.java:21)
at DAO.CategorieTechnicienDAO.main(CategorieTechnicienDAO.java:71)
```

the libraries (.jar)

[image: .jar]

Comment: can you list out the library (.jar) you are using for hibernate? It seems the library files issue.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kYja5.jpg

Comment: You are mixking hibernate versions (4.3.5 and 4.2.2) next you also have duplicate hibernate-commons-annotations on your class path.

Comment: please refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846184/error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-jboss-logging-logger-getmessagelogger. Hope it could be useful to you. Also use a common version and don't mix many versions for any particular library.