# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, dependencies

I am converting a Spring web project to a Maven project and I am getting this error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Apart from this error, seems that I have a lot of problems with dependencies, I am trying to fix them but I am a complete newbie into Maven:

> 6. oct 30, 2014 3:53:30 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile>
> 7. INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\a\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\revista2_local\WEB-INF\lib\el-api-2.2.jar)
>
>    - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class>
> 8. oct 30, 2014 3:53:30 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile>
> 9. INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\a\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\revista2_local\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar)
>
>    - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class>
> 10. oct 30, 2014 3:53:30 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
> 11. INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\a\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\revista2_local\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-javaee-5.0.0.GA.jar)
>
>     - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class>
> 12. oct 30, 2014 3:53:30 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
> 13. INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\a\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\revista2_local\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar)
>
>     - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
> 14. oct 30, 2014 3:53:30 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
> 15. INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\a\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\revista2_local\WEB-INF\lib\jsp-api-2.1.jar)
>
>     - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
> 16. oct 30, 2014 3:53:30 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
> 17. INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\a\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\revista2_local\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar)
>
>     - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

(Read the complete output for more details)

- Complete output -> http://pastebin.com/wKa2fVSP
- Pom.xml -> http://pastebin.com/sWCidx07
- Web.xml -> http://pastebin.com/uk9e4rUy

I am using Tomcat 7.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to have the org.jboss.logging.Logger class in two libraries:

jboss:jboss-common:jar:4.2.2.GA and org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA

the second one is used by hibernate and I would thing it is the correct one. I think you need to use the correct jboss-common version to not run into this issue.

Related Question: [Error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846184/error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-jboss-logging-logger-getmessagelogger)

Answer (score -1):

i removed jboss-common-3.2.3.jar,commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,commons-lang-2.3.jar and commons-collections-3.2.2. Then it worked for me. I was using widlfly 13 with java 10