# Jersey and Spring integration

Tags: spring, hibernate, jersey

I am developing a Jersey RESTful service using the Spring framework integration with Hibernate. I get a `NoSuchMethodException` on a `org.jboss.logging.logger.debugf` call. As I noticed, the class is indeed loaded from the `bean-validator.jar` included alongside the jersey-spring3 library, eventhough I have specifically referenced the jboss logging artifact.

Has anyone encountered this issue? And if so, how should I solve it?

**Update**

I have found a workaround, but it is far from being a solution. In order for the required classes to have the same signature, I have downgraded the hibernate-entitymanager to version 4.2.8.Final. However, this leads the way to other compatibility issues.

**Update 2**

In the end, I have chosen to implement the REST service functionality using the Spring Framework instead of using the aforementioned integration.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answers in the following post, your issue might be similar:

[Error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846184/error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-jboss-logging-logger-getmessagelogger)

Comment: I checked it out, but it is not the same issue. The problem is that another version of the logger class is being loaded from the bean-validator.jar