# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V WebLogic deployment

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, weblogic, jboss-logging

When I'm trying to deploy my application to WebLogic server(firstly I'm building war archive with Maven and then deploying with IntelliJ Idea WebLogic plugin) I'm getting this error:
What have I done wrong?

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
at org.hibernate.internal.NamedQueryRepository.checkNamedQueries(NamedQueryRepository.java:149)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:764)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:495)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:824)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:678)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:243)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:200)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:185)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1838)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2876)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:823)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

my dependencies are

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.0.0.CR4</hibernate.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846184/error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-jboss-logging-logger-getmessagelogger

Comment: Please search the Stack Overflow database (and Google) before posting here.

Comment: Solution here didn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very likely that you are using a version of a dependency that does not contain the method you are trying to use. Try to update your dependencies to a newer version.

Comment: My hibernate dependencies are the newest ones in Maven central repo, and I tried Jboss-logger 3.3.0 which are the newest one too, and no result.

Comment: Have you updated that dependency lately? If it was working before, maybe you want to go back to the previous dependency. According to JBoss 3.3.0 documentation, there is not a `debugf(String string)` method. http://docs.jboss.org/jbosslogging/latest/org/jboss/logging/Logger.html

Comment: yes, I added some spring dependencies recently, but not hibernate ones, I'll try older versions of Jboss logger

Comment: As an alternative, try to change the logging method. You can use `debugf(String string, Object... objects)` or just `debug(Object object)`.

Comment: This method is used inside hibernate.jar classes, I doubt I can change something here

Comment: I downgraded to Hibernate4 and not everything works fine. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I have just come across this issue when upgrading from Weblogic 12.1.3 to 12.2.1, using Hibernate 5.0.6.FINAL (The only thing I changed when I got this issue was the weblogic version - 12.1.3 was already configured for JPA 2.1)

I figured it's a classpath issue with different version of jboss-logging in the container - so I added an entry in my `weblogic-application.xml` file:

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.jboss.logging.*</wls:package-name>
</wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

After doing so Weblogic takes the proper jboss-logging version that is bundled with Hibernate and deploys my application successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have Jersey dependencies. If you still want to use Hibernate 5, see my answer here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/32278984/3525027

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Wildfly and the latest Hibernate version (5.0.3.Final). The solution was to remove jboss-logging completely from pom.xml since it obviously takes the logging from another library (weld-se).

I don't even know why I added jboss-logging. My projects works without it too.

Answer (score 0):

note for myself: add this to your jvm args to find the root cause

```
-verbose:class
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below param in webloic.xml file.

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>com.ctc.wstx.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.context.*</wls:package-name>
            <!-- DO NOT REORDER slf4j and jboss -->
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.jboss.*</wls:package-name>
                    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
```

or like this:

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
```