# Spring framework MVC - Hibernate exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm posting this issue concerning one of my projects in Java Spring Framework MVC - Hibernate. Please, take a look at my code and files below.
I suppose the problem is caused by 1)some missing or wrong dependencies and 2) some problems in the hibernate configuration. In advance, I thank you for your time and help.
Greg

### jars

[image]

### hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">adminC</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1//SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=perfDatabase;</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">adminC</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</property> 
<property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
  <mapping class="com.perfectino.factures.Article"/>
  <mapping class="com.perfectino.factures.Clients"/>
  <mapping class="com.perfectino.factures.Confirmation"/>
  <mapping class="com.perfectino.factures.Providers"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

### pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.perfectino</groupId>
    <artifactId>factures</artifactId>
    <name>mprojo</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version> -->
        <!-- <scope>runtime</scope> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version> -->
        <!-- <scope>runtime</scope> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
      <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>  
      <artifactId>jboss-common-core</artifactId>  
      <version>2.2.16.GA</version>  
      <scope>compile</scope>  
      <exclusions>  
        <exclusion>  
          <artifactId>jboss-logging-spi</artifactId>  
          <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>  
        </exclusion>  
      </exclusions>  
    </dependency>  
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

### Updated to

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.perfectino</groupId>
    <artifactId>factures</artifactId>
    <name>mprojo</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-common-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.16.GA</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging-spi</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

### .java

[image]

### hibernate configuration

I didn't find the solution to this problem.

[image]

### Error appearing when my vales has to be saved into the database

> > GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/factures] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested
> >     exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> >     org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;]
> >     with root cause java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> >     org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:28)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:24)
> >       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.(Configuration.java:86)
> >       at com.perfectino.factures.DAOManager.addObject(DAOManager.java:22)
> >       at
> >     com.perfectino.factures.HelloWorldController.setArticle(HelloWorldController.java:104)
> >       at
> >     com.perfectino.factures.HelloWorldController.addProduct(HelloWorldController.java:62)
> >       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> >     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> >     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> >     org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
> >       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)     at
> >     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)  at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
> >       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> >       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> >       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

### Updated to

> GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path
>   [/factures] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested
>   exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.StrategyRegistrationProvider:
>   Provider org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.StrategyRegistrationProviderImpl
>   not found] with root cause java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.StrategyRegistrationProvider:
>   Provider org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.StrategyRegistrationProviderImpl
>   not found     at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:324)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorBuilder.buildSelector(StrategySelectorBuilder.java:162)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:221)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.(Configuration.java:119)   at
>   com.perfectino.factures.DAOManager.addObject(DAOManager.java:22)  at
>   com.perfectino.factures.HelloWorldController.setArticle(HelloWorldController.java:104)
>     at
>   com.perfectino.factures.HelloWorldController.addProduct(HelloWorldController.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

### classpath

[image]

Comment: I think you have wrong version of jboss-logging jar. Try to find out correct version and add it.

Comment: Related question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846184/error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-jboss-logging-logger-getmessagelogger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846184/error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-jboss-logging-logger-getmessagelogger)

Comment: I put the jboss-logging, c3p0, hibernate-c3p0 jar in the classpath and added the dependencies. Now it throws me : "java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.StrategyRegistrationProvider: Provider org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.StrategyRegistrationProviderImpl not found] with root cause
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.StrategyRegistrationProvider: Provider org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.StrategyRegistrationProviderImpl not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second problem was related to duplicate jars present in the different libraries. So as solution I deleted the duplicates before being able to run the project. 
Thank you for your help.
Gregory

Comment: Can you Detail, which is the duplicate ? and which one did you remove ?